# Local transactions applicable to several MySQL database schemas?

Tags: mysql, spring, database-schema, distributed-transactions

I am developping a Spring application and I am considering having several MySQL schemas used by the same Spring application.

Can I use local transactions considering the above requirement or does using several MySQL schemas entails global/distributed transactions?

If local transactions and multiple MySQL schemas is possible, can anyone please provide advice as to how to configure Spring to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just seems that it is not possible to use local transactions and multiple MySQL schemas.